# Where to discuss or show mnemonics on SE?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have invented a number of new mnemonics and I am wondering whether there is a part of SE where I could answer my own question about what is a good mnemonic for something with my own mnemonic. For example: Question: What is a good mnemonic for the light primaries? Answer: The initials of "Roy G Biv" are RGB which recalls red, green, blue which are the light primaries.

Comment: Mnemonics might be a subject for [psychology.se], but not as a discussion type question, I'm sure that you realize we don't do those on SE. The usual recommendation - read their help centre for advice on how to ask questions. An additional thought, you might find a way to make it on-topic at [interpersonal.se], the same advice applies.

Comment: What has Interpersonal Skills to do with mnemonics? @ARogueAnt.

Comment: For all I know the OP (you) may be a parent or an educator and need effective mnemonics for students of a variety of ages and backgrounds. Communication would seem to be essential, since "best mnemonics" would seem to depend on so many factors such as age, experience, cultural and linguistic background etc.. Just covering all bases.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Okay, but it seems like a long shot.

Comment: "Roy G Biv" is not new. I learnt it 50 odd years ago to remember the colours of a rainbow ... red orange yellow green blue indigo violet

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not claiming that "Roy G Biv" is new, only that I seem to be the first to have noticed that besides recalling the colors of the rainbow with the letters ROYGBIV of "Roy G Biv", it's possible to *also* it to recall the three light primaries with the initials RGB of "Roy G Biv". Since so many people know "Roy G Biv" already, it's very easy to learn to use it for recalling the light primaries, simply by realizing that this feature was always there, unnoticed by everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the site the mnemonic is *about*. Some examples of lists of mnemonics:

- [Top 10 math mnemonics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/927412/228959)
- [Mnemonics for remembering physical data](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2064/77072) (closed)

and more specific ones:

- ["Magnetic mnemonics"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2702/77072)
- [Mnemonics for learning the days of the week](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/38392/18673)

Since mnemonics are part of education, sites which focus on teaching/learning a specific subject might have those questions as well:

- [Mnemonics for some properties in mathematics](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/13999/6053)

(but there's no site in the network for physics educators or science education in general).

But honestly, I don't think a self-answered question about a mnemonic you invented is going to be well-received. IMHO you're better off posting it on Twitter or other social media.

Comment: Upvoted. Great answer. "I don't think a self-answered question about a mnemonic you invented is going to be well-received." That is my guess too. There seems to be an excessively strong sentiment against anyone openly creating something new and showing it on SE, and I can't understand it. Surely it's one of the things the option of answering your own question is for? But/and in my experience answering my own question has often ended in my answer being deleted, which I also don't understand.

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh the answer your own question feature is (as far as I know, I am by no means a complete expert on this) supposed to be used when you have an actual question that you had, cannot find the answer through googling or some other extremely easy method, later find an answer, and then use the function of answer your own question

Comment: @EkadhSingh "supposed to be used when you have an actual question that you had, cannot find the answer through googling or some other extremely easy method, later find an answer" seems to imply that it should be used when no answer to my question existed and I invented my own solution, as in this case, where there was no answer to the question of what is a mnemonic for the light primaries until I created one.

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh Another way of phrasing Eladh’s message is: like Wikipedia, SE is not for publishing original research. We are not a journal. Trying to use the platform to draw eyes and attention to your original ideas is what causes people to downvote.

Comment: @DanBron I expect you are correct, and you have put it rather clearly, but I still don't understand *why* it matters to voters whether I found a good answer to a good question in a book, on a website, or in my own mind. I wasn't doing research when I realized that the initials of Roy G Biv are those of the light primaries, I just stumbled on the fact. What exactly is the difference to the voters whether I stumbled on it on a website, or I stumble on it on my own? After all, the website owner or forum participant may have stumbled on it himself or herself and then added it to the website. 1/2

Comment: @DanBron The comparison with Wikipedia seems only partially valid. With Wikipedia everything you add has to come from a reputable source although in practice what is a reputable source seems to be a difficult question. SE seems to me not to be much like that in practice. Figuring out answers to questions and/or stating your opinion as an answer seems acceptable at SE, except when answering your own question. I'm out of my depth here, I know, due to being a noob to SE, and usually just seeing my stuff voted up or down with little explanation (that I could understand/believe). I like SE though.

Comment: Could you please suggest how I could edit my question to make it better? I got a notice saying I might get blocked if I ask another bad question without editing my existing questions.

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh I'm not sure if this one can be improved. I guess people just didn't like it. The problem is not just this downvoted question; you have quite a few other questions (including five which are now deleted). Best would be to make sure your next few questions *are* well-received.

Comment: I'd forgotten about the deleted questions. Thanks for reminding me about those. Any ideas for how I can make sure my next few questions are well-received?

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh here is a link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188/295232

Comment: Thanks for the link. I asked a question and it is at eleven upvotes. I am pleased about that. Imagine my surprise when I tried to ask another question and got a notice saying I have reached my question limit. Some kind of mistake, surely?